# Vuex: state updates, but computed property doesn't

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component which takes a property called 'endpoints' from the store, adjusts it slightly...

```
computed: {
            ...mapState(['endpoints']),
            adjustedEndpoints () {
                if (this.endpoints){
                    return this.endpoints.map(x => {
                        x.displayName = x.name;
                        return x;
                    })
                }
            },
```

...and passes it to a table component in the template:

```
    <b-table show-empty
             stacked="md"
             :items="adjustedEndpoints"
             :fields="fields"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :filter="filter"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
             :sort-direction="sortDirection"
             @filtered="onFiltered"
    >
```

The issue is that when I edit an endpoint's properties, I see it change in the Vue component state, but this is not reflected in the rendered component until reload. I am guessing that the adjustedEndpoints() function is not being called automatically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `displayName` part of each endpoint *before* your computed runs?

Comment: No, it's not. The endpoints just have a 'name' property, but for some reason, Boostrap Vue Table doesn't like this...

Comment: [Vue is not able to detect](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) new property additions. You will need to use Vue.set (or this.$set).

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but it's not working: 
```   
adjustedEndpoints () {
             if (this.endpoints){
              return this.endpoints.map(x => {
               this.$set(x, x.displayName, x.name)
               return x;
              })
                }
```

Comment: Possibly, `this.$set(x, 'displayName', x.name)`.

Comment: That works in the sense that it sets the property, but the component still does not re-render on property change (meaning that the function is not re-run.)

Comment: How is the property changed?

Comment: On the initial table render, it shows the name of each endpoint, and this name is drawn from the displayName property.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to understand; you are passing `adjustedEndpoints` to `b-table`. If I understand correctly, for now, the first render, that renders correctly and the displayName gets to the `b-table` and renders as you expect. Then, at some point, you change an `endpoint`, but the `b-table` doesn't update the way you expect? If that is the case, how *exactly* do you change the `endpoint`? I ask because, as mentioned above, Vue cannot always detect changes to an object or an array *depending on how you update it* which means that `adjustedEndoints` may not run after you change endpoint.

Comment: I change the endpoint like this: I use Axios to make a request to the backend. The backend returns an updated endpoint, which I then commit in a mutation, where I replace state.endpoints with a new copy:
```
  updateEndpoint (state, endpoint) {
   state.endpoints = state.endpoints.map(x => {
    if (x.id === endpoint.id)
     return endpoint;
    return x;
   });
  }
```

Comment: That looks ok. Can you put together a small working example showing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.

In my initial state in the Vuex store, I did not declare the 'endpoints' property.

That was the entire problem.